# "GenerateResource" task failed in winform c# app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have problem while building my project as error is shown in picture. I am facing this problem after changing a variable name in the whole solution. for further detail i am waiting for response. I tried to revert all my changes but after reverting it is showing this error " Error 36 The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occured in GDI."

Comment: That is the error statement

Comment: Error 36 The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)
   at System.Drawing.Image.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization

Answer (score 0):

If you want something flexible, where you don't need to recompile, then the DB might be your best option.

Try restarting Visual Studio with Admin Privilege and Rebuild the same
A corrupted image file in a .resx file is technically capable of tripping this exception as well. Delete resources from the .resx file until the problem disappears.

Comment: i have added an existing project and then add it's reference to the added project and create it's object. then i replace it with existing static objects name throughout the solution by mistake and then revert my changes

Comment: still issue prevails?visual studio version using ?

Comment: is it not possible to know about the corrupted file directly instead of deleting one by one.

Comment: 2013 visual studio.

deleted all resources but still problem. Same error

Comment: restarted with admin privi ?

Comment: i always use with admin privileges due to menifest file and restated my system but same issue

Comment: i am not able to even copy my winform design. when i press ctrl+c it shows GDI+ error. :(